# Android studio не пишет в лог

Tags: android, java, android-studio

Android studio не пишет в лог ничего для моего пакета приложений, а в NoFilter пишет все подряд, кроме логов приложения. Раньше помогала перезагрузка приложения, а сейчас и телефон отсоединял - не помогает. В чем может быть дело?

Comment: Похоже, баг версии, у меня та же беда после обновления.

То пишет, то нет, очень часто пишет, но с задержкой несколько минут.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Он действительно пишет всё подряд, в том числе и о вашем приложении.
Посмотрите параметр Log level. Там есть значения: Debug, Error и т.д.

Если вы используете Log.d(), вместо No filter выставьте ваше приложение (например: app:com.example.app01), а в Log level: Debug.

После этого logcat должен показывать сообщения для вашего приложения, в том числе и описанные вами в Log.d().

Comment: спасибо, но дело не в этом, как я писал, для моего пакета приложений нет логов, а в noFilter есть все логи, кроме приложения с любым левелом, это баг студио.

Comment: Понятно. Тогда можете попробовать просто сделать update до версии 1.0.2.

Comment: Было сделано, как только эта версия появилась

Comment: Вазможно надо включить опцию на телефоне вот для Meizu https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/739392/33271, для Huawei есть сервисное меню.

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогло удаление приложения через терминал прям из студии:

```
adb uninstall <package name>
```

и потом залил заново