# Не отображаются логи на реальном девайсе

Tags: android, android-studio

Не отображаются логи на реальном девайсе, в эмуляторе все работает хорошо. Девайс Meizu M3 Note, такая ошибка появляется:

```
 E/GED: Failed to get GED Log Buf, err(0)

       [ 03-13 10:06:09.725  3582: 3954 I/         ]
       elapse(include ctx switch):5655 (ms), eglInitialize
```

И еще одна ошибка:

> 03-13 15:18:20.190 17152-17152/? E/System: stat file error, path is
>   /data/app/com.example.opimand.sqlitequery-1/lib/arm64, exception is
>   android.system.ErrnoException: stat failed: ENOENT (No such file or
>   directory)

Код проекта:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";

    String name[] = { "Китай", "США", "Бразилия", "Россия", "Япония",
            "Германия", "Египет", "Италия", "Франция", "Канада" };
    int people[] = { 1400, 311, 195, 142, 128, 82, 80, 60, 66, 35 };
    String region[] = { "Азия", "Америка", "Америка", "Европа", "Азия",
            "Европа", "Африка", "Европа", "Европа", "Америка" };

    Button btnAll, btnFunc, btnPeople, btnSort, btnGroup, btnHaving;
    EditText etFunc, etPeople, etRegionPeople;
    RadioGroup rgSort;

    DBHelper dbHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase db;



    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnAll = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAll);
        btnAll.setOnClickListener(this);

        btnFunc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFunc);
        btnFunc.setOnClickListener(this);

        btnPeople = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPeople);
        btnPeople.setOnClickListener(this);

        btnSort = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSort);
        btnSort.setOnClickListener(this);

        btnGroup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGroup);
        btnGroup.setOnClickListener(this);

        btnHaving = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnHaving);
        btnHaving.setOnClickListener(this);

        etFunc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etFunc);
        etPeople = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPeople);
        etRegionPeople = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etRegionPeople);

        rgSort = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rgSort);

        dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
        // подключаемся к базе
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        // проверка существования записей
        Cursor c = db.query("mytable", null, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (c.getCount() == 0) {
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            // заполним таблицу
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                cv.put("name", name[i]);
                cv.put("people", people[i]);
                cv.put("region", region[i]);
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "id = " + db.insert("mytable", null, cv));
            }
        }
        c.close();
        dbHelper.close();
        // эмулируем нажатие кнопки btnAll
        onClick(btnAll);

    }

    public void onClick(View v) {

        // подключаемся к базе
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        // данные с экрана
        String sFunc = etFunc.getText().toString();
        String sPeople = etPeople.getText().toString();
        String sRegionPeople = etRegionPeople.getText().toString();


        String[] columns = null;
        String selection = null;
        String[] selectionArgs = null;
        String groupBy = null;
        String having = null;
        String orderBy = null;

        // курсор
        Cursor c = null;

        // определяем нажатую кнопку
        switch (v.getId()) {
            // Все записи
            case R.id.btnAll:
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "--- Все записи ---");
                c = db.query("mytable", null, null, null, null, null, null);
                break;
            // Функция
            case R.id.btnFunc:
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "--- Функция " + sFunc + " ---");
                columns = new String[] { sFunc };
                c = db.query("mytable", columns, null, null, null, null, null);
                break;
            // Население больше, чем
            case R.id.btnPeople:
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "--- Население больше " + sPeople + " ---");
                selection = "people > ?";
                selectionArgs = new String[] { sPeople };
                c = db.query("mytable", null, selection, selectionArgs, null, null,
                        null);
                break;
            // Население по региону
            case R.id.btnGroup:
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "--- Население по региону ---");
                columns = new String[] { "region", "sum(people) as people" };
                groupBy = "region";
                c = db.query("mytable", columns, null, null, groupBy, null, null);
                break;
            // Население по региону больше чем
            case R.id.btnHaving:
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "--- Регионы с населением больше " + sRegionPeople
                        + " ---");
                columns = new String[] { "region", "sum(people) as people" };
                groupBy = "region";
                having = "sum(people) > " + sRegionPeople;
                c = db.query("mytable", columns, null, null, groupBy, having, null);
                break;
            // Сортировка
            case R.id.btnSort:
                // сортировка по
                switch (rgSort.getCheckedRadioButtonId()) {
                    // наименование
                    case R.id.rName:
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "--- Сортировка по наименованию ---");
                        orderBy = "name";
                        break;
                    // население
                    case R.id.rPeople:
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "--- Сортировка по населению ---");
                        orderBy = "people";
                        break;
                    // регион
                    case R.id.rRegion:
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "--- Сортировка по региону ---");
                        orderBy = "region";
                        break;
                }
                c = db.query("mytable", null, null, null, null, null, orderBy);
                break;
        }

        if (c != null) {
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                String str;
                do {
                    str = "";
                    for (String cn : c.getColumnNames()) {
                        str = str.concat(cn + " = "
                                + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(cn)) + "; ");
                    }
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, str);

                } while (c.moveToNext());
            }
            c.close();
        } else
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Cursor is null");

        dbHelper.close();
    }

    class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public DBHelper(Context context) {
            // конструктор суперкласса
            super(context, "myDB", null, 1);
        }

        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "--- onCreate database ---");
            // создаем таблицу с полями
            db.execSQL("create table mytable ("
                    + "id integer primary key autoincrement," + "name text,"
                    + "people integer," + "region text" + ");");
        }

        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Без кода здесь не помочь и выложите стектрейс более подробный

Comment: Попробуйте удалить приложение с устройства. и заново запустить его на нем

Comment: Такое ощущение, что у вас не хватает какой-то нативной либы, системы пытается найти нативную либу подходящую для архитектуры девайса *arm64* - судя по логам и поэтому и валится. Покажите дерево каталогов вашего APK

Comment: Алексей, пробовал и не раз.    Brmaley, тоже такое ощущение. Как показать дерево каталогов APK ? Не могу найти APK в установленных программах на устройстве в папке Android/Data

Comment: 28.06.2017 на мой meizu m2 note прилетела обнова прошивки Flyme 6.1.0.0G. С тех пор в логе при попытке вывести лог или систем аут вижу те же самые ошибки:
27958-27958/com.example.avereskun.myapplication E/System: stat file error, path is /data/app/com.example.avereskun.myapplication-2/lib/arm64, exception is android.system.ErrnoException: stat failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
27958-28092/com.example.avereskun.myapplication E/GED: Failed to get GED Log Buf, err(0)
Ошибка связана именно с мейзу и именно с 64 разрядными устройствами.
Кто смог побороть плз отпишитесь.

Comment: @Opimand отметь решением если мой ответ если помог)) мне он помог была таже проблема.

Answer (score 2):

> Settings -> Accessibility -> **Developer options** -> advanced
>   logging->set "Allow all"

Для Meizu MX4(Flyme 6.1.0.0) и M2(Flyme 6.1.0.0G) немного по другому:

> Settings->Accessibility - > **Developer Options** -> Performance
>   optimization -> Advanced logging -> set "Allow all"

Значение по умолчанию исключает показание Log.v() и Log.d()